# Get filename and extension from an absolute path

Tags: ant

In an Ant buildfile I have a path stored in an Ant property: `${file}`.

How can I get just the filename and extension without the full path?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [Basename task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html)

```
<basename property="filename" file="${file}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, strange that there is no way to avoid antcontrib or script injections.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a much better way to do it. Don't know why I didn't think of it before.